# Is it possible to automate captcha code using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm automating this [irctc](https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf) site as hands on selenium webdriver.

It is asking me for captcha code along with username and password. Is there anyway to automate the captcha code?

Comment: The reason for using a captcha is to make sure the site is **not** automated but used by an actual human being ... So if there were a (simple) way for doing that, there would not be a point in using captchas. Your only chance would be that the site offers some kind of API apart from the user interface you are trying to automate.

Comment: Generally it shouldn't be possible, captchas exist to make sure the site is used by a human and not a robot. In your specific case it would be possible with a simple OCR library. The site you are referring to has a very poor captcha implementation: captchas should be hard for computers to guess, but that one is easily hackable with some OCR.

Comment: Why down vote ? i am new on this site and just looking for an answer.

Comment: there are also several services providing captcha-solving.. you can also try them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously failed to understand what CAPTCHA is; [from WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA):

> A CAPTCHA (a backronym for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart") is a type of challenge-response test used in computing to determine whether or not the user is human.

As was already mentioned in other answers and comments, there are several possible attacks to defeat this. You can get links to several other options from the same [WikiPedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA#Circumvention). But note that all of these are more of a proof-of-concept, rather than an out-of-the-box solution.

Since you tagged your question with Selenium, it is possible that you may be using this in an **environment that you control**, such as test environment at your work. In such a scenario, the easiest solution is to ask your developers to introduce a "test" flag for any non-production deployments. When this flag is active, a predefined phrase will always pass the CAPTCHA for testing purposes. However, you should still have a full-pass test, with everything turned on as if real production.

Answer (score 0):

1.try import this javasc ocr lib or other ocr lib. https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js

2.read the result and pick only upper case char

Comment: Hello @Shylock Gou, I have tried above solution, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *proper* way to automate captcha using Selenium WebDriver. 
The only way to run an automated test script involving captcha is to have sufficient delay when the captcha appears so that a *human* can enter it on the field provided.