# URL parsing in python by using selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to parse the URL in python, and since the page detected as Block Url and Asking me CAPTCHA for unblocking request I resorted to using selenium web driver. However, Can anybody explain how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'parsing a URL'? Do you want to parse the HTML that is served under the URL?

Comment: I think that is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824548/is-it-possible-to-automate-captcha-code-using-selenium-webdriver/41826541

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output.